# Twilio - Masked Numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, twilio-api

I am developing an application where I'd like to implement masked numbers between users. The idea is...  Assume that you want to call me. Instead of seeing my number via the dashboard and/or order show page, you get a "Call" button. When you click this button it will cause your phone to ring. When you answer your phone, twilio will then attempt to connect you to my number  However, the number that you will see will be the twilio number rather than mine. And... if I ring the number I will be connected to the application team rather than being able to ring you back directly.

I have been trying to implement this in Rails and I checked your tutorial about masked numbers but I am not sure I understand how is this working: how do i send to twilio the two numbers i want to connect.
What is the purpose of Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new, and how do I start the call?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To build the flow where a user clicks a button and receives a callback which connects them to you, you need to do the following:

First, you'll need to take the user's number alongside the "Call" button. Or perhaps you already have their number from their account. Either way, you need their number at this point.

When they click the "Call" button in the action that responds you need to [use the Twilio REST API to make the call to their number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls). Your action might look a bit like this:

```
def call
  client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV["ACCOUNT_SID"], ENV["AUTH_TOKEN"])
  client.calls.create(
    from: ENV["TWILIO_NUMBER"],
    to: params[:phone_number],
    url: connect_call_url
  )
  redirect_to order_path
end
```

This assumes a few things. You need your Twilio account sid and auth token from the [Twilio console](http://twilio.com/console). You also need a Twilio number. In this example I'm storing them in the environment, but you could use `secrets.yml` or whatever.

I have also passed a `connect_call_url` to the call creation method. This should be a URL that routes to an action that will return some TwiML to connect the first call onto your number using the [`<Dial>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial). That is where `Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new` comes in. This action might look like:

```
def connect_call
  response = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new
  response.dial caller_id: ENV["TWILIO_NUMBER"] do |dial|
    dial.number ENV["YOUR_NUMBER"]
  end
  render xml: response.to_xml
end
```

In this case I also have your number stored in the environment. If this number is actually stored against an order, then you will need to get that from the database yourself.

Note also that I added the [`caller_id` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-caller-id) with a value of the Twilio number. This ensures that each user only sees the Twilio number.

For the final part, you want it such that ringing the Twilio number will connect you to the application team. For this you need another action that will return different TwiML. You'll want to set your Twilio number's Voice URL to this URL, so that when incoming calls are made to the number they are directed in this way.

This TwiML is pretty much the same as before, you just need to replace your number with the application team's number. Something like:

```
def inbound_call
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new
  response.dial do |dial|
    dial.number ENV["APP_TEAM_NUMBER"]
  end
  render xml: response.to_xml
end
```

Let me know if this helps at all.
    end

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I am almost there now, but I still have an error. This is my code: `def connect_call(user_phone,twilio_number) response = Twilio::TwiML::VoiceResponse.new response.dial caller_id: twilio_number do |dial| dial.number user_phone end render xml: response.to_xml end` In the console i get : `Twilio::REST::RestError (Unable to create record: Url is not a valid URL: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Dial callerId="+4420332*****"><Number>+4477438*****</Number></Dial></Response>):`

Comment: It's quite hard to read the code in a comment like this. It looks like you're setting the `url` when making the call directly to the TwiML though. You need to send an actual URL that when requested responds with the TwiML. Does that make sense?